# Biologically inspired ANNs

Tags: neural-networks, pattern-recognition, bioinformatics

Does anyone know what kinds of pattern classifier artificial neural networks are more biologically inspired?

Comment: I would recommend you have a look at "Theoretical Neuroscience" by Dayan  and Abbott (2001). As for the differences between ANNs and their biological counterpart, MacKay (2003) offers a small comparision. Moreover, you might also be interested in "On Intelligence" by Hawkins (2004).

Answer (score 1):

Convolutional Neural Networks are biologically inspired by the virtual cortex's arrangement in mammals. For example the sensitivity of vision system to local receptive fields is one of the defining properties of convolutional nets.